# python - pass the appropriate variable (parameter) to a function

Tags: python

I am looking for an efficient and cleaner way of executing the below simplified code. Currently *train_loader* or *test_loader* is copied into *enumerator* and this operation is rather expensive. Is there a way of eliminating this copy operation and get the right variable inside enumerate()?

```
    for phase in ['train', 'val']:
        if phase == 'train':
            enumerator = train_loader 
        else:
            enumerator = test_loader

        for i, (data,targets) in enumerate(enumerator):
            ....
```

Comment: What makes you think this operation is expensive?

Comment: No copy takes place there. `=` does not copy.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, the `phase` -> `enumerator` is redundant, and `phase` is not otherwise used, so:

```
for enumerator in [train_loader, test_loader]:
    for i, (data, targets) in enumerate(enumerator):
        ....
```

I don't, however, know why the assignment I got rid of is expensive.  As others say in the comments, it's just a copy of a reference.  Whatever's being pointed to is not. copied. If it turns out that you do need `phase` later on, I don't see a problem with what you had.

Comment: I came from C++ background and thought '=' creates new memory and copy all the contents in to it (didn't know 'enumerator' here is just like a reference variable in C++). Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: No problem.  I haven't touched C++ in a long time.  I bet I would be making the same mistake over there, but in reverse.